# Set up network teaming on Centos 7

Tags: centos, networking, rhel

I've been preparing for my RHCE exam and on of the objectives is to configure network teaming/bonding.

I'm currently trying to configure a server with two interfaces and combine them to a teaming interfaces. When I use another VM (in the same subnet) to ping the teaming interfaces, i get response back. But when I try to shutdown a interface (nmcli con down eth0) the ping stops. If I start the interface and shutdown the other one then the ping will continue.

If I start over on a new VM then it randomly selects a interface. Sometimes its eth0 and sometimes its the other interface (eno33554992)

I'm currently using two Centos 7 virtual machines in VMware workstation with NAT.

Can someone look at my config and commands and tell me whats wrong with it?
Thanks in advance!

My commands are:

```
nmcli con add type team con-name team0 ifname team0
nmcli con mod team0 ipv4.addresses "192.168.4.210/24 192.168.4.1" ipv4.method manual
nmcli con add type team-slave con-name eth0 ifname eth0 master team0
nmcli con add type team-slave con-name eth1 ifname eno33554992 master team0
nmcli con up eth0
nmcli con up eth1
nmcli con up team0
```

My configuration is:

```
[root@server1 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-team0
DEVICE=team0
DEVICETYPE=Team
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=team0
UUID=a950a224-9cb0-48ed-90f4-4dc019aa665b
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR0=192.168.4.210
PREFIX0=24
GATEWAY0=192.168.4.1
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes

[root@server1 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=eth0
UUID=6648eb26-c793-44fc-8685-2b5cbaadfac5
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
TEAM_MASTER=team0
DEVICETYPE=TeamPort

[root@server1 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=eth1
UUID=dd2231b3-3530-4d6c-a8ff-6860d003cc0a
DEVICE=eno33554992
ONBOOT=yes
TEAM_MASTER=team0
DEVICETYPE=TeamPort

[root@server1 ~]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master team0 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:70:d6:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno33554992: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master team0 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:70:d6:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: team0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
    link/ether 00:0c:29:70:d6:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.4.210/24 brd 192.168.4.255 scope global team0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe70:d6a6/64 scope link tentative dadfailed
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to set it like this

```
nmcli con add type team con-name team0 ifname team0 config '{"runner": {"name": "activebackup"}}'
```

If you would like to make sure that the interface keeps on going even when you deactivate the other interface.